# Example micoservice app with CQRS and Event Sourcing

Tags: microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm planning to create a simple microservice app (set and get appointments) with CQRS and Event Sourcing but I'm not sure if I'm getting everything correctly. Here's the plan:

1. docker container: public delivery app with REST endpoints for getting and settings appointments. The endpoints for settings data are triggering a RabbitMQ event (async), the endpoint for getting data are calling the command service (sync).
2. docker container: for the command service with connection to a SQL database for setting (and editing) appointments. It's listening to the RabbidMQ event of the main app. A change doesn't overwrite the data but creates a new entry with a new version. When data has changed it also fires an event to sync the new data to the query service.
3. docker container: the SQL database for the command service.
4. docker container: the query service with connection to a MongoDB. It's listening for changes in the command service to update its database. It's possible for the main app to call for data but not with REST but with ??
5. docker container: an event sourcing service to listen to all commands and storing them in a MongoDB.
6. docker container: the event MongoDB.

Here are a couple of questions I don't get:

- let's say there is one appointment in the command database and it already got synced to the query service. Now there is a call for changing the title of this appointment. So the command service is not performing an UPDATE but an INSERT with the same id but a new version number. What is it doing afterwards? Reading the new data from the SQL and triggering an event with it? The query service is listening and storing the same data in its MongoDB? Is it overwriting the old data or also creating a new entry with a version? That seems to be quite redundant? Do I in fact really need the SQL database here?
- how can the main app call for data from the query service if one don't want to uses REST?
- Because it stores all commands in the event DB (6. docker container) it is possible to restore every state by running all commands again in order. Is that "event sourcing"? Or is it "event sourcing" to not change the data in the SQL but creating a new version for each change? I'm confused what exactely event sourcing is and where to apply it. Do I really need the 5. (and 6.) docker container for event sourcing?
- When a client wants to change something but afterwards also show the changed data the only way I see is to trigger the change and than wait (let's say with polling) for the query service to have that data. What's a good way to achieve that? Maybe checking for the existing of the future version number?
- Is this whole structure a reasonable architecture or am I completely missing something?

Sorry, a lot of questions but thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s take this one first.

> Is this whole structure a reasonable architecture or am I completely
>   missing something?

Nice architecture plan!  I know it feels like there are a lot of moving pieces, but having lots of small pieces instead of one big one is what makes this my favorite pattern.

> What is it doing afterwards? Reading the new data from the SQL and
>   triggering an event with it? The query service is listening and
>   storing the same data in its MongoDB? Is it overwriting the old data
>   or also creating a new entry with a version? That seems to be quite
>   redundant? Do I in fact really need the SQL database here?

There are 2 logical databases (which can be in the same physical database but for scaling reasons it's best if they are not) in CQRS – the domain model and the read model.  These are very different structures.  The domain model is stored as in any CRUD app with third normal form, etc.  The read model is meant to make data reads blazing fast by custom designing tables that match the data a view needs. There will be a lot of data duplication in these tables. The idea is that it’s more responsive to have a table for each view and update that table in when the domain model changes because there’s nobody sitting at a keyboard waiting for the view to render so it’s OK for the view model data generation to take a little longer.  This results in some wasted CPU cycles because you could update the view model several times before anyone asked for that view, but that’s OK since we were really using up idle time anyway.

When a command updates an aggregate and persists it to the DB, it generates a message for the view side of CQRS to update the view.  There are 2 ways to do this.  The first is to send a message saying “aggregate 83483 needs to be updated” and the view model requeries everything it needs from the domain model and updates the view model.  The other approach is to send a message saying “aggregate 83483 was updated to have the following values:  …” and the read side can update its tables without having to query.  The first approach requires fewer message types but more querying, while the second is the opposite.  You can mix and match these two approaches in the same system.

Since the read side has very different table structures, you need both databases.  On the read side, unless you want the user to be able to see old versions of the appointments, you only have to store the current state of the view so just update existing data.  On the command side, keeping historical state using a version number is a good idea, but can make db size grow.

> how can the main app call for data from the query service if one don't
>   want to uses REST?

How the request gets to the query side is unimportant, so you can use REST, postback, GraphQL or whatever.

> Is that "event sourcing"?

Event Sourcing is when you persist all changes made to all entities.  If the entities are small enough you can persist all properties, but in general events only have changes.  Then to get current state you add up all those changes to see what your entities look like at a certain point in time.  It has nothing to do with the read model – that’s CQRS.  Note that events are not the request from the user to make a change, that’s a message which then is used to create a command.  An event is a record of all fields that changed as a result of the command.   That’s an important distinction because you don’t want to re-run all that business logic when rehydrating an entity or aggregate.

> When a client wants to change something but afterwards also show the
>   changed data the only way I see is to trigger the change and than wait
>   (let's say with polling) for the query service to have that data.
>   What's a good way to achieve that? Maybe checking for the existing of
>   the future version number?

Showing historical data is a bit sticky.  I would push back on this requirement if you can, but sometimes it’s necessary.  If you must do it, take the standard read model approach and save all changes to a view model table.  If the circumstances are right you can cheat and read historical data directly from the domain model tables, but that’s breaking a CQRS rule.  This is important because one of the advantages of CQRS is its scalability.  You can scale the read side as much as you want if each read instance maintains its own read database, but having to read from the domain model will ruin this.  This is situation dependent so you’ll have to decide on your own, but the best course of action is to try to get that requirement removed.

In terms of timing, CQRS is all about eventual consistency.  The data changes may not show up on the read side for a while (typically fractions of a second but that's enough to cause problems).  If you must show new and old data, you can poll and wait for the proper version number to appear, which is ugly.  There are other alternatives involving result queues in Rabbit, but they are even uglier.